# Unable to identify the installed vnc server type

Tags: networking, 20.04, tightvncserver, vncviewer

On my Ubuntu 20.04 lts pc, when I run `/home/ziomario# vncviewer 127.0.0.1:0`, I see the following

[image]

Basically it appears the `TightVNC` client that asks for a password,but I don't know what is this. But most of all,I don't know to which server it belongs .So,there is a service that start the vnc server and I've tried a lot of passwords,but none worked (including the password that I have chosen to login into Ubuntu). I've installed the xen hypervisor,but I'm not sure that the vnc server belongs to it. Infact the vnc server is ready BEFORE I start xen with these commands :

```
sudo /etc/init.d/xencommons start

sudo /etc/init.d/xendomains start

sudo /etc/init.d/xen-watchdog start

sudo /etc/init.d/xendriverdomain start
```

before to launch those commands,between the process I don't see any xen and qemu instance,but the vnc server is up. I want to understand why. I'm not able to identify any vnc process :

```
root@ziomario-I9:/etc/xen# ps -ef | grep vnc
root       11920    7204  0 23:26 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto vnc
```

maybe it belongs to xenbus or xenwatch ?

```
root@ziomario-I9:/etc/xen# ps ax | grep xen

109 ?        S      0:00 [xenbus]   

110 ?        S      0:00 [xenwatch]  11901 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto xen
```

neither the tightvncserver is installed :

```
root@ziomario-I9:/etc/netplan# apt remove tightvncserver

"tightvncserver" is not installed,so it can't be removed
```

or

```
root@ziomario-I9:/etc/netplan# apt remove realvnc-vnc-server

can't find "realvnc-vnc-server"

root@ziomario-I9:/etc/netplan# sudo lsof -i :5900

root@ziomario-I9:/etc/netplan# sudo netstat -tnlp
Connessioni Internet attive (solo server)
Proto CodaRic CodaInv Indirizzo locale        Indirizzo remoto       Stato       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      45055/systemd-resol 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2455/sshd: /usr/sbi 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1837/cupsd          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:42809           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2241/rpc.mountd     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2828/smbd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:46335         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2268/containerd     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:24800           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12584/synergys      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2049            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:902             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6019/vmware-authdla 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:34025           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2828/smbd           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:46127           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2241/rpc.mountd     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/init              
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:42929           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2241/rpc.mountd     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5939          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2567/teamviewerd    
tcp6       0      0 :::21                   :::*                    LISTEN      2269/vsftpd         
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      2455/sshd: /usr/sbi 
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      1837/cupsd          
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                    LISTEN      2828/smbd           
tcp6       0      0 :::8096                 :::*                    LISTEN      2199/EmbyServer     
tcp6       0      0 :::2049                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::53122                :::*                    LISTEN      4362/docker-proxy   
tcp6       0      0 :::38787                :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::14500                :::*                    LISTEN      1/init              
tcp6       0      0 :::902                  :::*                    LISTEN      6019/vmware-authdla 
tcp6       0      0 :::35819                :::*                    LISTEN      2241/rpc.mountd     
tcp6       0      0 :::139                  :::*                    LISTEN      2828/smbd           
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      1/init              
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      2677/apache2        
tcp6       0      0 :::51441                :::*                    LISTEN      2241/rpc.mountd     
tcp6       0      0 :::60915                :::*                    LISTEN      2241/rpc.mountd
```

Comment: Add the output of `sudo lsof -i :5900` and `sudo netstat -tnlp`, please

Comment: refresh the page.